# How to force Unity Editor to use OpenGl single-threaded rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need Unity to run with *single threaded* Opengl rendering on Windows.  There is a command line option in the player and in the editor to do this (-force-opengl -force-gfx-direct).  However, it *appears* as though it is just there for developer debugging since it is only a command line option (not available in Player Settings anymore) and I need it in production.

Question 1: Is there a way to bake single threaded opengl rendering into the windows player so I don't have to create a windows shortcut to launch it?

Question 2: Any idea if this option is going to disappear soon? Given that it is no longer on the Player Settings dialog for Windows, I'm nervous that it is being deprecated...

More background on why:
I'm writing a native plugin to Unity 2019.2 that does OpenGL calls AND calls back into Unity methods that are marked as [MonoPInvokeCallback] to perform things like loading resources.

My problem is that Unity does multithreaded rendering for OpenGL by default, so you need to perform your OpenGL calls on their rendering thread (how to do that is described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html)).

BUT: The Unity scripting APIs throw exceptions if you access them outside of the "main unity thread" and my code needs to do things like load a resource using a MonoPInvokeCallback AND make an OpenGL call in one function. Thus the need to shut off multi-threaded rendering.

Comment: Do you _**really**_ need to make both loads and OpenGL calls in the same function? I can almost bet that a task/scheduling system would work.

Comment: Of course not. This is software, right? I can do anything.  However, I want to avoid the cost of rewrites to the core of my game engine if I can.

Comment: I believe unity has an option in other settings tab, its a checkbox called MultiThreaded Rendering. it may help

Comment: That option is available in the iOS build, but not the PC/Mac/Linux Standalone build.  That's why I'm worried it may disappear from the command line too...